# Using AngularJS dependency inside a template

Tags: angularjs

I would like to set the `max-height` of a `div` to be `$window.innerHeight`. The following code fails:

```
<div ng-style="{'max-height': $window.innerHeight}" style="overflow-y: auto">
```

My walk-around was to use a scope variable:

```
$scope.divnHeight = $window.innerHeight;
<div ng-style="{'max-height': divHeight}" style="overflow-y: auto">
```

Is there any way to achieve a `ng-style` to `$window` binding?

Thanks

Comment: can you create a plunker with an example of your code? you can fork this for easy setup: http://plnkr.co/edit/eqKz9wgyzm8LOz6pZAN0?p=info

Comment: You're missing 'px' in the ng-style, just noticed, see my answer below with a link to the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're missing 'px' in the ng-style**

See Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eqKz9wgyzm8LOz6pZAN0?p=preview

To answer your question, no... any variable you wish to use in HTML must be a scope variable.

If the window height is changing, then you can use a watcher to bind the variable to the window height:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
   return $window.innerHeight; // the thing to watch
}, function(newValue, oldValue) { // the function to run when the value changes
   console.log(newValue);
   $scope.divnHeight = $window.innerHeight;
});
```

Update:

try adding this into your controller, this just registers a function to fire when you resize:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    console.log("Fire resize");
    $scope.divnHeight = $window.innerHeight;
};
```

Also, the size may stay the same because you are using max-height rather than height, in which case the height depends on the content, try using height and see if that makes a difference:

```
<div ng-style="{'height': divHeight + 'px'}" style="overflow-y: auto">
```

Comment: Thanks EliteOctagon! On my chrome browser, this code is executed only once, even when changing the window size... So that this solution is no better than my original solution.

Comment: @Michael, you need to use to mention the unit of measure when defining the height, in this case it would be pixels